# Log Shipping Server Restart Problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, log-shipping

I have Log Shipping setup from Primary Server A to Destination B. Server B is both Destination and Monitoring server.
Yesterday, we restarted both servers around the same time for patching. On the Log Shipping Status report, it says Primary Source Backups are Not Up to Date and Failing. So I run the LS backup manually, and it still says backup has not occurred in 2000 minutes??

The Destination Monitoring Server says Copies and Restores are Success.
How do I resolve this problem on Source Server A?

Comment: Does LS Backup job runs as per schedule?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the stored procedures that are provided to help manage Log Shipping.  If you Google "sp_refresh_log_shipping_monitor" you will find that it's just one of many stored procedures available.  It appeared to be the most likely to help you in this situation.  Hopefully, it will keep you from having to resort to tearing down Log Shipping and reconfiguring it.